# how to create multiples for mod_rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I have a giant site that I am implementing a mod_rewrite on. This is my first time dealing with this so I'm still working out some major kinks. That being said, I have reg-ex figured out for all of my single pages via:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z_-]+)/?$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

which in turn yields something like this:

```
www.blah.com/page
```

With the above rule, I have changed my `php` files to be the same name, except without the `.php` extension. So for example, the previous pretty url's `.php` is named `page.php`

Now, I have made a url goal list for all of my dynamic multi part url pages. Those will ideally look something like this:

```
www.blah.com/page/extention_of_page/id/title-title
```

or

```
www.blah.com/page/id
```

Obviously I can't rename each `.php` for each or when it comes to dynamics it gets a little trickier, so naturally I'm going to categorize my files in folders and feed them that way.

So now that you should have a good idea of what I'm trying to achieve, what would the rewrite rule ( or two ) that would encompass the last two url examples?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd switch around how you're using mod-rewrite.

Use a 404 page or index page which translates requests.

Then in mod_rewrite you can pull out each element between / and pass them across...

index.php?var1=page&var2=extention_of_page$var3=id&var4=title-title

Then process whats been sent across in the index page and display results accordingly

Sone good examples here : [linky](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php)

However this way kind of implies some DB querying to get the content which from the sound of things is going to be a lot easier to maintain that many differentluy named php files

HTH